# Delete or merge a user account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Turns out I have an older account which was set up several years ago.

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/5524/criggie

I do not have access to the email address that would be associated.
Is it possible to merge that account with my real one?  If not, can it just be deleted?  Or should it be left as-is ?

My real account is https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/19705/criggie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Stack Exchange procedure for merging two accounts.

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
>   sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to
>   merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team
>   will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm
>   your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email
>   address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts